# How does the lengths of the Gram-Schmidt orthogonal basis of a lattice basis change after lll reduction?

Tags: lenstra-lenstra-lovasz, reduction

Assuming there is a lattice basis $B=\{b_1,...,b_n\}$, we use $B^*=\{b_1^*,...,b_n^*\}$ to denote the Gram-Schmidt orthogonal basis, where $b_i^*=\pi_i(b_i)$ and $\pi_i(b_i)$ denotes the projection of $b_i$ on the orthogonal complement of the space $span(b_1,...,b_{i-1})$. We use $\|b_i^*\|$ to denote the Euclidean norm of $b_i^*$. I want to know how $\min_{1\leq i \leq n}{\|b_i^*\|}$ changes after LLL reduction in detail. Is there any reference for this question? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is not a formal result with respect to this question, there is a widely accepted empirical observation for "typical" lattices known as the Geometric Series Assumption (see the [8th slide of this talk](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/lattice-reduction-and-attacks.pdf) by Martin Albrecht for example). This states that we believe that the $||b_i^*||$ form a decaying geometric progression so that the least value is $||b_n^*||$. As the product of the $||b_i^*||$ is the determinant of the lattice, we expect that for $1\le i\le n$ we have
$$||b_i^*||\cdot||b_{n-i}^*||\approx\Delta^{2/d}$$
where $d$ is the degree of the lattice and $\Delta$ its determinant. It follows then that we expect
$$\min_{1\le i\le n}||b_i^*||=||b_n^*||\approx\frac{\Delta^{2/d}}{||b_1||}.$$
Entering your favourite expression for the length of the shortest vector in the LLL basis (e.g. $||b_1||=\delta_0^d\Delta^{1/d}$) will give an expression such as
$$\min_{1\le i\le n}||b_i^*||\approx\delta_0^{-d}\Delta^{1/d}.$$

Comment: Although this estimate is a little rough, it answers my doubts to some extent. Thanks for your help!